# problems to show images from firebase to my website how to solve?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

mi js

```
var imgs = document.getElementById("galeria");

function mostrarImagenDeFirebase() {
 imagenesFbRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
var datos = snapshot.val();
var result = "";
result += '<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">';
for (var key in datos) {
  var images = datos[key].url;
  result += '<img class="owl-lazy" height="500" data-src="'+images+'" alt="">';
  console.log(images);
       }
  result += ' </div>';
imgs.innerHTML += result;
});
}

<div class="row"id="galeria">

 </div>
```

does not show the page the images only leaves the space but does not show it

Comment: You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `data-src=` with `src=`, also please close your image tags - `<img ... />`

Comment: thanks !!!!!! although I'm using owlcarousel.js and do not apply the animations I need